# how to save data in data base table has two primary key using jpa spring boot angular js

Tags: angularjs, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot

**THIS IS MY ENTITY**

1. my probelem is i don't knwo why my http requtte dosn't work
2. i'm using ARC application to test the requette  this is the error
3. "status": 500,
4. "error": "Internal Server Error",
5. "exception":"org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException",
6. "message": "Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.Long' to required type 'com.projet.pfe.entities.AF' for property 'fa'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.Long' to required type 'com.projet.pfe.entities.AF' for property 'fa': no matching editors or conversion strategy found",
   "path": "/saveactaf/2/2/333"
       package com.projet.pfe.entities;

   ```
   import java.io.Serializable;

   import javax.persistence.Entity;
   import javax.persistence.Id;
   import javax.persistence.IdClass;
   import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
   import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

   @IdClass(ActiviteAF.class)
   @Entity
   public class ActiviteAF implements Serializable  {
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       @Id
       @ManyToOne
       @JoinColumn(name="idact")
       private Activite activite;
       @Id
       @ManyToOne
       @JoinColumn(name="idaf")
       private AF fa;
       private double montant;
       public Activite getActivite() {
           return activite;
       }
       public void setActivite(Activite activite) {
           this.activite = activite;
       }
       public AF getFa() {
           return fa;
       }
       public void setFa(AF fa) {
           this.fa = fa;
       }
       public double getMontant() {
           return montant;
       }
       public void setMontant(double montant) {
           this.montant = montant;
       }
       public ActiviteAF(Activite activite, AF fa, double montant) {
           super();
           this.activite = activite;
           this.fa = fa;
           this.montant = montant;
       }
       public ActiviteAF() {
           super();
       }

   }
   ```

   **this is my Repository**

   package com.projet.pfe.DAO;

   ```
   import java.util.Collection;

   import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
   import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
   import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

   import com.projet.pfe.entities.ActiviteAF;

   public interface ActiviteAFRepository extends JpaRepository<ActiviteAF,Long> {
       @Query("select af from ActiviteAF af where af.activite.idActivite like :x")
       public Collection<ActiviteAF> activitebyid(@Param("x") Long id);

   }
   ```

   **this is the Rest Controller**

   package com.projet.pfe.service;

   ```
   import com.projet.pfe.DAO.AFRepository;
   import java.util.Collection;

   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

   import com.projet.pfe.DAO.ActiviteAFRepository;
   import com.projet.pfe.DAO.ActiviteRepository;
   import com.projet.pfe.entities.AF;
   import com.projet.pfe.entities.Activite;
   import com.projet.pfe.entities.ActiviteAF;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;


   @RestController
   public class ActAFRestService {
       @Autowired
       private ActiviteAFRepository actafmet;
       @Autowired
           private ActiviteRepository actr;
           @Autowired
           private AFRepository afr;

          @RequestMapping(value="/saveactaf/{idact}/{idaf}/{montant}",method=RequestMethod.POST)
          public ActiviteAF save(@PathVariable(name="idact")long idact,@PathVariable(name="idaf")long idaf,@PathVariable(name="montant")double montant){
              Activite a = new Activite();
              AF af = new AF();
              a = actr.findOne(idact);
              af = afr.findOne(idaf);
              ActiviteAF aaf = new ActiviteAF(a,af,montant); 
              return actafmet.save(aaf);
          }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution , juste make a singel. Id and change the others to a simple annotation(forign keys) , this solution work but need a test( activite,af ) in the case of adding new object .